# Iframe . Get same iframe's point from differents mobile devices

Tags: html, css, iframe

I'm iframing a page (not same domain), position the iframe to a specific element of the page (moving the margin top), then zoom to the element using scale's css propriety.

I'm accomplishing using this code:

```
iframe {
 -webkit-transform: scale(40.75);
  margin-top: -2525px;
}
```

But when I try to view the page from a mobile device different from the one I used to test my page, I got different results.

There is a way to show the same iframe's point to different mobile devices, without change each margin for each device?

Comment: Why "-2525px" ? What's you're purpose ?

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that margin-top or any other margin rule has to be changed at every screen-width. One possible way to have the iframe always at one position is to declare a position:absolute and set bottom-top, right-left attributes, and then the iframe will always be at that position.
In any other case, you have to put media-queries for every other device-width and set different margin-top.